# Throttling REST requests in C#

Tags: c#, rest

I'm rather new to C#, and found relevant subclassing examples surprisingly hard to come by. I've whipped up this class that appears to work, but am pretty sure this is not optimal:

```
private class ThrottledRestClient
{
    int pause;  // mininum ms between requests
    double rpm;  // max requests per minute
    long last_request_time;
    RestClient client;
    public ThrottledRestClient(string url, HttpBasicAuthenticator auth, double rpm = 60)
    {
        this.client = new RestClient(url);
        this.client.Authenticator = auth;
        this.rpm = rpm;
        this.pause = (int)((60 / rpm) * 1000);
    }

    public IRestResponse Execute(RestRequest request)
    {
        long now = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        int wait = pause - (int)((now - this.last_request_time) / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond);
        if (wait > 0)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Waiting ms: " + wait);
            Thread.Sleep(wait);
        }
        this.last_request_time = DateTime.Now.Ticks;

        return this.client.Execute(request);
    }
}
```

How could this be better? Is there an existing solution I haven't found?

Comment: Are these requests async or sync?

Comment: Sync, but I'm running batches of things that don't depend on each other.

Comment: this is not thread safe. several thread will update and read last_request_time concurrently

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm rather new to C#, and found relevant subclassing examples
>   surprisingly hard to come by

You just needed to try a bit harder! You are doing pretty much what you were supposed to do logic wise. What you are trying to do here obviously (maybe), is a specialization of a `RestClient`, so the `RestClient` class is the best candidate to inherit from. From there you may override the Execute method.

Don't be afraid to use verbose variables. The rpm name could be firstly reminded as rotations per minute which doesn't really apply here. Also try to name your instances fields in `camelCase`, you may or may not prefix them with `_`.

I also didn't get why your pause is `(60 * 1000) / rpm = 1000` with the default rpm, but one thing I know is that you don't need to store it in a field because it may be calculated. I would also recommend using Environment.TickCount instead of DateTime.Now.Ticks, which is more performant.

With those modifications the code would become the following:

```
public class ThrottledRestClient : RestClient
{
    private readonly int _requestsPerMinute;
    private int _lastRequestTime;

    public ThrottledRestClient(int requestsPerMinute)
    {
        _requestsPerMinute = requestsPerMinute;
    }
    public override IRestResponse Execute(IRestRequest request)
    {
        int elapsedTime = Environment.TickCount - _lastRequestTime;
        int pause = (60/_requestsPerMinute)*1000;
        int wait = pause - elapsedTime;
        if (wait > 0)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(wait);
        }
        var response = base.Execute(request);
        _lastRequestTime = Environment.TickCount;
        return response;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** To answer you comment. You can use this client like you would use the previous one eg:

```
var client = new ThrottledRestClient(60);
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("user", "password");
//so on so forth;
client.BaseUrl = "http://google.pt";
client.Request(new RestRequest());
```

Comment: I used `60 / rpm` in case the API specified something else, e.g. 1 request per minute, so the pause would then be 60000. I don't see why you mention a more performant alternative yet keep calculating the pause.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman Gotcha. I was referening to Environment.TickCount. This Tickcount is more suitable to calculate an epalsed time then DateTime.Now.Ticks.

Comment: Indeed it is. Strange that C# uses two different concepts named `Tick`.

Comment: How do I tell your code what the base URL is?

Comment: @CeesTimmerman edited the answer to address your question.

Comment: if several thread could call Execute at the same time this implementation is broken

Comment: @skyde Most APIs are not thread safe by default. If you want to support multithreading you can use thread local storage per instance.

Comment: @Bruno Costa I added a more generic answer.

Answer (score 2):

You might want a Generic throttling class  see : [Throttling class](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/157478/throttling-class)

```
var throttler = new Throttler(_requestsPerMinute, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
```

And in your request processing simply call throttler.ThrottledWait(1);

```
public override IRestResponse Execute(IRestRequest request)
{
    throttler.ThrottledWait(1);
    return base.Execute(request);
}
```

Comment: Is this thread-safe?

Comment: @Cees Timmerman yes the Throttler class is thread-safe